# Altium - How to lock information window on the top left?

Tags: altium

I somehow accidently unlocked the display on the top left in the PCB routing view (which shows the active layer, snap grid etc.) and now it follows the y-axis of my cursor, is it possible to fix it to the top left again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Shift+G

Move your mouse so that the window is where you want it to be fixed and press Shift+G.

If you let your mouse rest in the editing window a while the information window will expand to show you some shortcuts associated with it.

You're lucky you're not using Cadence. I once undocked the command window and found out it can never be re-docked without an re-install. A known bug for years apparently.